# Passport.js local strategy. How to avoid direct-typing-in-the-address-bar access to the protected route?

Tags: node.js, express, security, mongoose, passport.js

This is my app.get:

```
app.get('/secrets', async (req, res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated) {
    try {
      const foundUsers = await User.find({'secrets': {$ne: []}});
      res.render('secrets', {usersWithSecrets: foundUsers});
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
});
```

I'm using, express, express-session, mongoose, passport, passport-local.

The problem I'm facing is while my register and login routes work well, The "secrets" route - the one you supposed to see only when authenticated, I am able to access just by typing the full route into the address bar without logging in. It does not seem to be a session-related issue because I get no obstacle in getting to secrets even after I erase all stored credentials on my database and use a browser I never used before (which does not have any cookies stored yet)